# Style other cards when hover over one CSS

Tags: html, css, web, hover

on a part of my site I have a set of 6 cards arranged 3x3 using flexbox, and I want it so when the user hovers over one card, all the others will change background colour or get dimmer (haven't decided yet). Here's an extract of my text, when I hover over a child, it changes all the cards after it, but I would also like it to do the ones before too (so every other card but itself!

Here is my code:

```css
#page3container {
  height: 70%;
  width: 70%;
  background: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  left: 15%;
  top: 22%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.page3card {
  height: 40%;
  width: 30%;
  background: rgb(50, 71, 139);
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(50, 71, 139);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.card3Title {
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.card3Title h3 {
  font-family: 'Play';
  width: 80%;
  color: #d83a3a;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 5%;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.card3Number {
  width: 20%;
}

.card3Text {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Play';
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.new {
  background: rgb(88, 78, 215);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.new:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgb(88, 78, 215);
  transition: 0.5s;
  height: 42%
}

***.new:hover~.new {
  background: red;
}

*** .cardnumber {
  height: 100%;
  width: 45%;
  text-align: left;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-size: 19vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.cardcontent {
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.cardcontent h1 {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40%;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

#inner {
  height: 60%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  position: relative;
}

#inner img {
  width: 8vw;
  height: 8vw;
  margin: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.cardcontent h1 {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 2.2vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="page3card new">
  <div class="cardnumber">1</div>
  <div class="cardcontent">
    <h1 class="cardtitle"><strong>Download Chrome</strong></h1>
    <div id="inner"><img src="img/chrome-icon.webp" id="chrome"></div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="page3card new">
  <div class="cardnumber">2</div>
  <div class="cardcontent">
    <h1 class="cardtitle"><strong>Create an account</strong></h1>
    <div id="inner"><img src="img/person-icon.png"></div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="page3card new">
  <div class="cardnumber">3</div>
  <div class="cardcontent">
    <h1 class="cardtitle"><strong>Link Devices</strong></h1>
    <div id="inner"><img src="img/link-icon.png"></div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="page3card new">
  <div class="cardnumber">4</div>
  <div class="cardcontent">
    <h1 class="cardtitle"><strong>Block websites</strong></h1>
    <div id="inner"><img src="img/stop-icon.svg"></div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="page3card new">
  <div class="cardnumber">5</div>
  <div class="cardcontent">
    <h1 class="cardtitle"><strong>All set!</strong></h1>
    <div id="inner"><img src="img/check-icon.svg"></div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="page3card new">
  <div class="cardnumber">6</div>
  <div class="cardcontent">
    <h1 class="cardtitle"><strong>View reports</strong></h1>
    <div id="inner"><img src="img/report-icon.png"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

```
Many thanks!
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you try this yourself first. Questions asking for help without an attempt to solve the problem are likely to get closed. For more info, refer to [ask] and how to create a [mre].

Comment: Is `#page3container` the parent of all the cards?

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand exactly what you meant. But the following code makes the rest of the cards pale when the card is hovering and the selected card turns red.

```js
$('.page3card').on("mouseenter", function() {
        $('.page3card').each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('deactive');
        });
        $(this).removeClass('deactive');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }).on("mouseleave", function() {
       $('.page3card').each(function() {
           $(this).removeClass('deactive');
           $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
    });
```

```css
#page3container {
  height: 70%;
  width: 70%;
  background: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  left: 15%;
  top: 22%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.page3card {
  height: 40%;
  width: 30%;
  background: rgb(50, 71, 139);
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(50, 71, 139);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.card3Title {
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.card3Title h3 {
  font-family: 'Play';
  width: 80%;
  color: #d83a3a;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 5%;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.card3Number {
  width: 20%;
}

.card3Text {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Play';
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.new {
  background: rgb(88, 78, 215);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.new:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgb(88, 78, 215);
  transition: 0.5s;
  height: 42%
}

***.new:hover~.new {
  background: red;
}

*** .cardnumber {
  height: 100%;
  width: 45%;
  text-align: left;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-size: 19vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.cardcontent {
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.cardcontent h1 {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40%;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

#inner {
  height: 60%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  position: relative;
}

#inner img {
  width: 8vw;
  height: 8vw;
  margin: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.cardcontent h1 {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 2.2vw;
}
.active
{
    background:red;
}
.deactive{
    opacity:.6;
    background:#111;
}
```

```html
<div class="page3card new">
  <div class="cardnumber">1</div>
  <div class="cardcontent">
    <h1 class="cardtitle"><strong>Download Chrome</strong></h1>
    <div id="inner"><img src="img/chrome-icon.webp" id="chrome"></div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="page3card new">
  <div class="cardnumber">2</div>
  <div class="cardcontent">
    <h1 class="cardtitle"><strong>Create an account</strong></h1>
    <div id="inner"><img src="img/person-icon.png"></div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="page3card new">
  <div class="cardnumber">3</div>
  <div class="cardcontent">
    <h1 class="cardtitle"><strong>Link Devices</strong></h1>
    <div id="inner"><img src="img/link-icon.png"></div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="page3card new">
  <div class="cardnumber">4</div>
  <div class="cardcontent">
    <h1 class="cardtitle"><strong>Block websites</strong></h1>
    <div id="inner"><img src="img/stop-icon.svg"></div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="page3card new">
  <div class="cardnumber">5</div>
  <div class="cardcontent">
    <h1 class="cardtitle"><strong>All set!</strong></h1>
    <div id="inner"><img src="img/check-icon.svg"></div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="page3card new">
  <div class="cardnumber">6</div>
  <div class="cardcontent">
    <h1 class="cardtitle"><strong>View reports</strong></h1>
    <div id="inner"><img src="img/report-icon.png"></div>

  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me, this is not possible by just CSS, here is how you can achieve it by using javascript. And according to your need, you can modify or simplify it.

```js
function changeColor(active){
  if(active == "one"){
    document.getElementById('two').style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
    document.getElementById('three').style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
  }else if(active == "two"){
    document.getElementById('one').style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
    document.getElementById('three').style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
  }else if(active == "three"){
    document.getElementById('two').style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
    document.getElementById('one').style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
  }
  
}

function againChange(active){
  if(active == "one"){
    document.getElementById('two').style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    document.getElementById('three').style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }else if(active == "two"){
    document.getElementById('one').style.backgroundColor = "red";
    document.getElementById('three').style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }else if(active == "three"){
    document.getElementById('two').style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    document.getElementById('one').style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}
```

```css
#parent #one, #two, #three{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}
#parent #one{ background-color: red}
#parent #two{ background-color: blue}
#parent #three{ background-color: green}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Roshan</title>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div id="parent">
      <div id="one" onmouseover="changeColor('one')" onmouseout="againChange('one')"></div>
      <div id="two" onmouseover="changeColor('two')" onmouseout="againChange('two')"></div>
      <div id="three" onmouseover="changeColor('three')" onmouseout="againChange('three')"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

This is not possible by just CSS because there is no "previous sibling" selector in CSS.